# Use the Positive-Definitness of $V$ to Establish the Existence of Nested Sets $B_\delta \subset \hat{\Omega_\gamma} \subset B_\epsilon$

Tags: general-topology

Let $V \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth, positive-definite map. Define $\gamma := \min_{{x \colon ||x|| < \epsilon}}V(x)$ and $\Omega_\gamma := \{x | V(x) \leq \gamma \}$ Let $\Omega_{\gamma} = \Omega_\gamma \cap B_\epsilon$.

I'm stuck on the following questions wich seem rather trivial. Prove that:

$$(a) \hat{\Omega_\gamma} \text{ is compact}$$
$$(b) 0 \in \hat{\Omega_\gamma}$$
$$(c) \hat{\Omega_\gamma} \neq {0}$$

I understand that it is clearly bounded, but I am not sure how to argue it is closed. I want to say the complement is the union of two open sets, but the complement of the open ball is closed. For (b) and (c), I feel I need to use the fact that it is positive-definite to prove that $0$ is in the set, and it is not a signleton by continuity. However, I'm rather unfamiliar with this.

Comment: What does it mean for $V$ to be positive definite?

Comment: @ronno I believe it’s the definition from the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function

Comment: If you mean the second definition from that article ($V(x) > 0$ for $x$ near $0$ and possibly $V(0) = 0$) then either $\gamma = 0$ with $\Omega_\gamma = \{0\}$ which contradicts (c), or $V$ is allowed to be constant $1$ in which case $\hat{\Omega_\gamma} = B_\epsilon$ is not compact.

Comment: I'm assuming the sentence after the definition of $\Omega_\gamma$ is supposed to be defining $\hat{\Omega_\gamma}$, which you should correct.